# Best practices for where to store data about how to format specific columns returned from mySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, formatting, xampp

For a school project, I have to create a database using XAMPP, php, and html/css. It's a database reflecting the game EVE online.

I have a function that submits a query and formats the returned data into a simple html table. 
Sometimes I find myself wanting to format the data in some columns differently, and it's not always dependent on type. For instance, for my Corporation table, I want to format the corporation names (primary key) as links that will in turn generate new tables with more in depth information about that corporation. However I don't necessarily want to do this for all tables.

Whats the best practice for storing this kind of formatting data about the columns? Where should this metadata reside? In new columns, new tables or somewhere in php?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding a link is not formatting a value. You do not store this anywhere, you add the links from code where necessary.

Comment: What I mean is I need to markup different pieces of data differently. I may want to markup up one column as links, another as paragraphs etc. Then, later, I want to call the same table generation function and have it markup the data from a  different query differently. To do that, the table generation function needs some metadata about how to markup the data.

Comment: You probably have that meta data already: foreign keys will be links, text data becomes paragraph, etc. Do not try to overnenginer this.